# Is there a safer alternative for EOF? It's not working in my case

Tags: c++, binaryfiles, file-handling, eof

I'm working on my school project in which I've got to handle files in c/c++ .
I'm worried about using `while((c=fgetc())!=EOF)` because:

What if the binary code of the file contains `11111111` which has same value as EOF and the program finishes unwantedly ?

here is a sample code in which I first create a binary code containing `-1` and the program finishes before indeed reaching end of file.

```
int main()
{
    FILE *p;

    fopen_s(&p, "my.binn", "wb");
    char c;
    char result;

    for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++)
    { //putting some bytes in file
        result = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < 8; r += 2)
        {
            result |= (1 << (7 - r));
        }
        putc(result, p);
    }

    result = 0;

    for (int r = 0; r < 8; r++)
    { //putting a byte of 11111111
        result |= (1 << (7 - r));
    }

    putc(result, p);

    for (int t = 0; t < 3; t++)
    { //again putting some bytes in file
        result = 0;
        for (int r = 0; r < 8; r += 2)
        {
            result |= (1 << (7 - r));
        }
        putc(result, p);
    }
    fclose(p);

    fopen_s(&p, "my.binn", "rb");

    while ((c = fgetc(p)) != EOF)
    { //here this loop was expected to continue until end of file(7 bytes) but it prints only three stars
        cout << "*";
    }
    fclose(p);
    return 0;
}
```

could anyone help me with this please??

Comment: oops ! you're right ! sorry I'm just new to file handling

Comment: C or C++? Choose one. Even though C++ is mostly a superset of C the way things are done can be very different.

Comment: @user12648660 would you elaborate?

Comment: So you mean if it's `char c;` then only 3 stars are printed? I thought C and C++ were the same in this matter...

Comment: @eerorika is correct. Haven't coded in C++ for a while and I were confused. My apologies

Comment: I suggest you then tag C++ (if that is what you use) and stdio, and explain at start of question that you don't want to use iostream etc, only C-compatible part of standard library.

Comment: Or just tag C if you don't want to distract answerers and actually prefer C answers. But don't tag both.

Comment: @hyde so it means that if i use both stdio and iostream in my project I'm going to face such problems? because I'm new to both and I thought It's ok

Comment: If you have both an iostream object and C `FILE*` accessing same file in a way that makes their buffering have conflict, then yeah, problem. Just reading a file is ok, but reading stream (like stdin) or any writing is going to be problematic. Just don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EOF` is a (macro for a) negative int. `fgetc` reads an unsigned char cast to an int. As long as the range of unsigned char is smaller than that of int, such conversion never results in a negative number, in which case there is no overlap with `EOF`.  <sub>I don't know how exotic systems where sizeof(int) == 1 can deal with this.</sub>

But in your attempt, you're comparing the result of the assignment operation, which is lvalue to the left hand operand, which is a char converted from int. And as such, your concern is valid.

To fix the program, read the input into an int variable, compare that with `EOF`, and *then* convert to char.

Comment: thanks a million . it really helped me with all my confusion